# package javax.jnlp is declared in module java.jnlp, which is not in the module graph

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, java-9

I have a project that uses Java webstart technology. I decided to upgrade the Java version from 8 to 9. However, I faced the following error on compiling:

```
error: package javax.jnlp is not visible
import javax.jnlp.DownloadServiceListener;
        ^
(package javax.jnlp is declared in module java.jnlp, which is not in the module graph)
```

I tried to include `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\lib\javaws.jar` to the classpath, but still the same issue remains.

Comment: Did you add `requires javaws;` to your `module-info.java`?  If so could you add the build version and your module-info.java file please.

Comment: @nullpointer I was not using `module-info.java` at all. All other packages were included by default except `javaws`. I think the reason behind this is what @Nicolai explained in his answer. Anyway, the problem has been resolved by using modules. Thanks

Comment: Similar: [*“package javax.xml.soap is declared in module java.xml.ws, which is not in the module graph”*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46084302/642706)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like *java.jnlp* is not resolved by default for code on the class path (much like [Java EE modules](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/#Dependencies-On-Java-EE-Modules)). The solution is to add it explicitly with `--add-modules java.jnlp` (both `javac` and `java` accepts that parameter).

This option is discussed in [*JEP 261: Module System*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261) or in [this blog post](https://blog.codefx.org/java/five-command-line-options-to-hack-the-java-9-module-system/#Extending-The-Module-Graph-With--add-modules).

Comment: Nicolai is correct, more details in "Root modules" section of JEP 261. The original question also mentioned lib/javaws.jar - that JAR file is used when JDK 8 or older releases use the deploy bits in JDK 9, it's not intended to be used on the class path.

Comment: `--add-modules xxxx` is not a **solution**, it is a **workaround**.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA:
Add javaws.jar to Classpath(File -> Project Structure -> SDKs ->Class)
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-**version**\lib\javaws.jar