# "package javax.xml.soap is declared in module java.xml.ws, which is not in the module graph"

Tags: java

So I took the SOAP example at [Working Soap client example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948927/working-soap-client-example/15949858#15949858) , put it into a file `SOAPClientSAAJ.java`, and tried compiling it (Openjdk 9 on Debian):

```
t@h ~/javatest> javac SOAPClientSAAJ.java 
SOAPClientSAAJ.java:1: error: package javax.xml.soap is not visible
import javax.xml.soap.*;
                ^
  (package javax.xml.soap is declared in module java.xml.ws, which is not in the module graph)
1 error
```

After Googling some, I found out that compiling and running as

```
t@h ~/javatest> javac --add-modules java.xml.ws SOAPClientSAAJ.java
t@h ~/javatest> java --add-modules java.xml.ws SOAPClientSAAJ
```

works. See also this video for general background: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8bpKYDrF5I&t=20m17s

Now, questions:

1. Shouldn't the compiler automatically add the module java.xml.ws ? (since it obviously knows it is needed) Is this a bug in javax.xml.soap ?
2. Why is the --add-modules option not documented in my man pages? (openjdk 9 in Debian)
3. What should I write in the .java file to automatically add the java.xml.ws module?

Comment: Similar: [*package javax.jnlp is declared in module java.jnlp, which is not in the module graph*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45419935/642706)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a result of the [new Java 9 modules](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html). The `javax.xml.soap` package is [actually a Java EE package](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/), and so now isn't visible. The current workaround is to either use the `--add-modules`, as you've done, or to [modularize your code](https://labs.consol.de/development/2017/02/13/getting-started-with-java9-modules.html).

Modularizing your code requires restructuring it into modules, and including a `module-info.java` file that specifies the modules you're using. In your case, specifying `java.se.ee` would give access to all the EE modules.

Comment: Be aware that the **`--add-modules` workaround is for Java 9 and Java 10 only**. Java 11 and later removes the [Java EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) related modules entirely from [Java SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform%2C_Standard_Edition), as responsibility is relocated to the [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee) organization. For details, see [*JEP 320: Remove the Java EE and CORBA Modules*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320)