# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : javax/xml/soap/SOAPException

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap, spring-ws

I have created a Web Service using Spring. It works fine when running it on my embedded tomcat server. However when I package it as a JAR file and run it with `java -jar` command, I am receiving this exception.

My service sends a simple soap request and the server response is:

```
 "exception": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
    "message": "javax/xml/soap/SOAPException",
```

That's the response I get in Postman.

Any ideas where I can look for the problem.

Comment: do you create a fat jar, ie. are dependencies getting packaged along with the jar?

Comment: There is a class file that doesn't exist in your project. You probably didn't package your jar dependencies correctly. This error will come up if there is a missing class file.

Answer (score 41):

Adding the following in pom file solved the issue

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.soap/javax.xml.soap-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: worked for me. My SOAP-API-Client Code (Springboot WAR) was running fine through "mvn spring-boot:run" but throwing this error on Tomcat 8.5. However not sure what causes "mvn spring-boot:run" to succeed in first place. Can it be that local JDK/JRE or Maven's underlying jar plays some role there ?

Comment: worked for me.
jdk 9;
javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api 1.4.0;
and also com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl 1.5.1; as mentioned by Harisudha

Answer (score 35):

JavaSE 8 includes package `java.xml.soap`.
JavaSE 9 moved package `javax.xml.soap` to the module `java.xml.ws`.
Modules shared with JEE (like `java.xml.ws`) are included in JavaSE 9, but are
- [deprecated](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html) for removal from a future version of JavaSE, and
- [not on the default module path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F640FA9D-FB66-4D85-AD2B-D931174C09A3).

A quick workaround is to either
- run the jar with JRE 8: `$MY_JRE8_HOME/bin/java -jar my.jar`, or
- add a module for JRE 9: `java --add-modules java.xml.ws -jar my.jar`

Longer term, JavaSE projects that use modules like `java.xml.ws` must explicitly include the module like other libraries.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46359097
See [JDK 9 Migration Guide: Modules Shared with JEE Not Resolved by Default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-954372A5-5954-4075-A1AF-6A9168371246)

(Reproduced NoClassDefError and workarounds with zipped SOAP web service project at https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/)

Answer (score 34):

Yes, In Java 11 java.xml.soap was completely removed.
*java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPException* can be removed by adding the 
following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-RC3</version>
</dependency>
```

But later, you will encounter , *javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found*.
This can be solved by adding the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope, it helps!

Comment: I can confirm that for Java 11 the implementation is missing: `com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl`. We did not need the `soap-api` definition.

Answer (score 17):

Add the following dependencies, it should work then

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Refer the following links for a running piece of code (SpringBootSOAPWS + Java10) 
[Github- SpringBoot Soap Server](https://github.com/coderish/Springboot-SOAPServer)
[Github- SpringBoot Soap Client](https://github.com/coderish/Springboot-SOAPClient)

Answer (score 15):

I imported this one to sort out the issue: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.soap/javax.xml.soap-api/1.4.0

Answer (score 7):

Adding this dependency will solve the issue.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

The JAX-WS dependency library “jaxws-api.jar” is missing.
Try:

- `compile group: 'javax.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-api', version: '2.3.1'` - for gradle or:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already closed for all above people but I am still facing this issue even though I have added
jakarta-xml.soap-api and saaj jars in classpath.

Anything that I am missing to make it work.Tried out using javax-.xml-soap-api as well instead of jakarta jar but still same error.Somehow its not able to identify the jar.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but are you by chance using the 4.x versions of the Jakarta libraries? I'm currently wrestling with that since Jakarta's package name changed with that version.

Comment: Same here..just started with 4.x upgrade and stuck with no-arg constructor issue for ProviderImpl

Comment: I ended up going back to an older Jakarta version. Until everything I use, uses the 4.x version I'll have to stick with this. Hoping when we move to Spring 3.x it may be more feasible to use Jakarta 4.x