# Running a Java EE application with Java 11

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-11

I have an application that uses the Java EE interfaces and JFX.

When I try to run it with Java 11 I get the following error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPException`

I do not have access to its source code and I don't expect it to be updated for Java 11 soon enough (it's a government mandated program to file tax declaration).

The software environment is Debian 10 that has Java 8 JRE Java 11 JRE and Java 11 JFX but no Java 8 JFX so running it with Java 8 does not seem to be an option.

I have tried fixing the error by installing the `libjaxws-java` package (the JAX-WS Reference Implementation that installs a bunch of jars to `/usr/share/java/` and `/usr/share/maven-repo/com/sun/xml/ws/` ) but it did not change anything - I suspect some additional parameters should be provided on the command line but I have no idea what.

The current command line looks like this:

```
java -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -jar boot.jar
java -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -DentityExpansionLimit=128000 -jar abevjava.jar cfg=cfg.enyk
```

What extra parameters should I provide to make it run?

Comment: This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626824/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-soap-soapexception

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54574003/3301492).