# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl'

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

I'm new at Spring Boot. And currently, I have a problem with the running the project.

there is the error as

```
 17:29:07.358 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'passPolicyController' defined in file [D:\Invent\admin\build\classes\java\main\kz\bsbnb\invent\admin\controller\PassPolicyController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'passPolicyServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\Invent\admin\build\classes\java\main\kz\bsbnb\invent\admin\service\PassPolicyServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'soapServices' defined in class path resource [kz/bsbnb/invent/admin/config/SoapConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [kz.bsbnb.invent.admin.soap.SOAPServices]: Factory method 'soapServices' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory]: Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at kz.bsbnb.invent.admin.AdminApplication.main(AdminApplication.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'passPolicyServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\Invent\admin\build\classes\java\main\kz\bsbnb\invent\admin\service\PassPolicyServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'soapServices' defined in class path resource [kz/bsbnb/invent/admin/config/SoapConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [kz.bsbnb.invent.admin.soap.SOAPServices]: Factory method 'soapServices' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory]: Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'soapServices' defined in class path resource [kz/bsbnb/invent/admin/config/SoapConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [kz.bsbnb.invent.admin.soap.SOAPServices]: Factory method 'soapServices' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory]: Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [kz.bsbnb.invent.admin.soap.SOAPServices]: Factory method 'soapServices' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory]: Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory]: Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:149)
    at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.instantiateBean(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:152)
    at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategies(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:134)
    at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategy(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:219)
    at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategy(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:203)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.initMessageFactory(WebServiceTemplate.java:353)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.initDefaultStrategies(WebServiceTemplate.java:342)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.<init>(WebServiceTemplate.java:130)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport.<init>(WebServiceGatewaySupport.java:65)
    at kz.bsbnb.invent.admin.soap.SOAPServices.<init>(SOAPServices.java:35)
    at kz.bsbnb.invent.admin.config.SoapConfig.soapServices(SoapConfig.java:50)
    at kz.bsbnb.invent.admin.config.SoapConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$865ef7a.CGLIB$soapServices$2(<generated>)
    at kz.bsbnb.invent.admin.config.SoapConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$865ef7a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8a82b797.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at kz.bsbnb.invent.admin.config.SoapConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$865ef7a.soapServices(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3296)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3501)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2711)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:139)
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 74 common frames omitted
```

and there is classes to consuming SOAP

Configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class SoapConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller () {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPaths("axis2.apache.org.xsd",
                "org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.common.xsd",
                "org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.service.dao.xsd",
                "org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.service",
                "org.wso2.carbon.user.api.xsd",
                "org.wso2.carbon.user.core.xsd",
                "org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.common.xsd",
                "org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.xsd",
                "org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.xsd",
                "org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.xsd",
                "org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier ("webServiceTemplate")
    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate () {
        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
        webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller());
        webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller());
        webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(messageSender());
        return webServiceTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public SOAPServices soapServices (Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        SOAPServices soapServices = new SOAPServices();
        soapServices.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        soapServices.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        soapServices.setMessageSender(messageSender());
        return soapServices;
    }

    private HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender messageSender () {
        return new HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender() {
            @Override
            protected void prepareConnection (HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
                String credentials = String.format("%s:%s", "admin", "admin");
                String encodedAuthorization = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(credentials.getBytes());
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("Basic %s", encodedAuthorization));
                super.prepareConnection(connection);
            }
        };
    }


}
```

Service class to generate methods

```
public class SOAPServices extends WebServiceGatewaySupport
{
    private final ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
    private final org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.service.ObjectFactory objectFactory = new org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.service.ObjectFactory();
    private final org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.ObjectFactory idpFactory = new org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.ObjectFactory();
    private final org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.xsd.ObjectFactory idPropFactory = new org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.xsd.ObjectFactory();

    @Autowired
    private WsoConstant wsoConstant;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier ("webServiceTemplate")
    private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;


    public List<String> getAllUsername ()
    {
        ListUsers request = factory.createListUsers();
        request.setFilter(factory.createListUsersFilter("*"));
        request.setLimit(100);
        ListUsersResponse listUsersResponse = (ListUsersResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(wsoConstant.getAdminEndpoint(), request);
        return listUsersResponse.getReturn();
    }
}
```

PassPolicyService Service class

```
@Service
public class PassPolicyServiceImpl implements PassPolicyService
{


    private final SOAPServices soapServices;
    public PassPolicyServiceImpl (SOAPServices soapServices) {this.soapServices = soapServices;}

    @Override
    public IdpPropPassDto getPassPolicy () throws InventException
    {
        IdpPropPassDto idpPropPassDto = new IdpPropPassDto();
        soapServices.getIdpResidentValues().getIdpProperties().forEach((key, val) ->
        {
            if (key.equals("passwordPolicy.min.length"))
            {
                idpPropPassDto.setMinLength(Integer.parseInt(val));
            }
            if (key.equals("passwordPolicy.max.length"))
            {
                idpPropPassDto.setMaxLength(Integer.parseInt(val));
            }
            if (key.equals("passwordPolicy.errorMsg"))
            {
                idpPropPassDto.setErrorMsg(val);
            }
            if (key.equals("passwordPolicy.pattern"))
            {
                idpPropPassDto.setPassPattern(val);
            }
        });

        return idpPropPassDto;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean updatePassPolicy (IdpPropPassDto idpPropPassDto) throws InventException
    {

        WsoPassProp passProp = soapServices.getIdpResidentValues();
        passProp.getIdpProperties().clear();
        passProp.getIdpProperties().put("passwordPolicy.min.length",idpPropPassDto.getMinLength().toString());
        passProp.getIdpProperties().put("passwordPolicy.max.length",idpPropPassDto.getMaxLength().toString());
        passProp.getIdpProperties().put("passwordPolicy.errorMsg",idpPropPassDto.getErrorMsg());
        passProp.getIdpProperties().put("passwordPolicy.pattern", idpPropPassDto.getPassPattern());

        return soapServices.updateResidentIdP(passProp);
    }
}
```

I thought it's happening because tried to @Autowire service class inside Service class. Then I tried to look up how to consume SOAP in https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/. And it didn't help to me.
I can't get what is the promlem here. Could you help my? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiler can not find class javax/xml/soap/SOAPException. I think this link can help you to solve problem [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : javax/xml/soap/SOAPException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626824/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-soap-soapexception/53976056)