# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPException

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror, soapexception

My system got a Java update recently from jre 1.8_331 to jre 1.8_341 and from then on, I face troubles with my workspace. This is the exception I get when I try to run my application.

```
    SEVERE: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPException
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:179)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.<init>(AxisClient.java:52)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:113)
    ......
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:91)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:150)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:76)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:71)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:116)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:217)
    at com.abb.se.ppc.client.ClientSessionControl.createNewModel(ClientSessionControl.java:336)
    at com.abb.se.ppc.client.ui.dialog_windows.ModelCreationWindow$2.buttonClick(ModelCreationWindow.java:121)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:200)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:163)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1015)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:377)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:54)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:158)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:119)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:432)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:404)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1422)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:379)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
    ... 77 more
```

I googled for some solutions, added axis jars to my classpath, also changed the Compiler compliance level to 1.8 from 16. Nothing worked.

I'm using jre1.8_341 and JDK 14.0.2.

Please help me what I can try further.

Comment: IMO A google (eventbus?) forum would be the best place to try to get answers on this

Comment: The error as shown is not produced by jre 1.8_341, but by a Java 9 or higher version. And Java doesn't contain a `javax.xml.soap.SOAPException` since Java 9. You need to make sure you have the appropriate library on your classpath. You also need to make sure you're using Tomcat 9 or lower, and not Tomcat 10 (otherwise you need to use `jakarta.xml.soap.SOAPException`).

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs. Adding `javax.xml.soap-api` solved the error for me!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following in pom file solved the issue

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.soap/javax.xml.soap-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I got this solution from [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : javax/xml/soap/SOAPException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626824/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-soap-soapexception/53976056#53976056)

Answer (score 0):

I think the package of SoapException has been moved in your new JDK version.
Have you tried running your application adding the new module (java.xml.ws) ?
Like this :

```
java --add-modules java.xml.ws -jar my.jar
```